# Reduce the number of lines

Tags: javascript

I have defined two charts below for example. But I use more than 50 charts in my code.
The difference between both charts are: chartNumber, containerNumber, id, text and data. Also the condition that is used for checking each chart at the beginning.

Working fiddle of the same: https://jsfiddle.net/2s93zb4j/12/ (pls check all 3 charts to view all of them)

Instead of repeating same lines of code for each chart, will I be able to reduce the number of lines using for loop or forEach. Thank you.

```
  //Chart1
  if (checkNA=== "NA") 
  chart0 = Highcharts.chart('container1', {
            id: 1,
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'NorthAmerica'
                }                
            }],
            series: [{
                data: NorthAmericaData,
                type: 'line',                
            }],

        });
   }

  //Chart2
  if (checkSA=== "SA") 
    chart1 = Highcharts.chart('container2', {
            id: 2,        
            yAxis: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'SouthAmerica'
                }                
            }],
            series: [{
                data: SouthAmericaDta,
                type: 'line',                
            }],

        });
  }
```

Comment: This might be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: BUt if you define a variable for each value that might change, you just need to set those variables correct and then you can call `Highcharts.chart` with those vars

Comment: Thank you, I will try posting in codereview.stackexchange as well

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 2):

A class would go a long way here.

```
class ChartObject {
  constructor(id, text, data) {
    this.id = id;
    this.yAxis = [
      {
        title: {
          text,
        },
      },
    ];
    this.series = [
      {
        data,
        type: 'line',
      },
    ];
  }
}

//Chart1
if (checkNA === 'NA') {
  chart0 = Highcharts.chart(
    'container1',
    new ChartObject(1, 'NorthAmerica', NorthAmericaData)
  );
}

//Chart2
if (checkSA === 'SA') {
  chart1 = Highcharts.chart(
    'container2',
    new ChartObject(2, 'SouthAmerica', SouthAmericaDta)
  );
}
```

Hope this helps.